# Only view access_log entries from a certain IP in SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, logging

I've got a large multi-year access_log and I need to view all of the entries for a certain IP address from SSH. The format is:

> 111.111.111.111 - ...
>
> 222.222.222.222 - ...
>
> 111.111.111.111 - ...

How would I only view the log entries for 111.111.111.111? I'm running CentOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grep for it is the easiest way.

```
grep "^111\.111\.111\.111\b" access_log
```

Comment: Strongly agree; small lightweight tools is the UNIX way.  That said, I'd modify the regexp to `"^111\.111\.111\.111"`.  It doesn't matter for that particular ip address, but `^1.3.2.4` will also match `153.214.56.37`.

Comment: Good point!  I think when the odds are against mismatches like that I tend to forget the escapes.

Comment: Cakemox, you ask good questions!  Of the 2^32 possible IP addresses, how many of them - if used unescaped - can also match other IP addresses; that is, how likely is a mismatch?  I'm no mathematician, and I'm especially poor at combinatorics, but if anyone reading has the tools to provide the answer, I'd love to know it.

Comment: I guess even escaping the IP might cause problems on the last octet, too.  Have to throw a \b in there for good measure.  As for the odds of a mismatch, no idea!  I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 2):

My obligatory [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) answer:

```
cat access_log | parallel --pipe -k grep ^111.111.111.111
```

Note that requires a relatively recent version of parallel to work.  The cool thing about this approach is it splits the file into multiple chunks and rungs grep on those chunks in parallel instead of running grep on the whole file.  The `-k` option ensures that the ordering stays correct.

For a very large file that could potentially be a lot faster than a simple grep.  Something to try, anyway.